# Covert DB2 Compress adaptive to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, db2

What will be equivalent query of below DB2 to PostgreSQL .

ALTER TABLE User.emp COMPRESS YES ADAPTIVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent. The only compression that takes place is the compression of large column values by the TOAST machinery, and that happens by default.

Comment: SO there is no need to execute above query in Postgres?

Comment: No, unless you want to get an error message from PostgreSQL, there is no need to run this statement.